# How to create a script to run on all devices on xCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, shortcut

my question is simply: ¿Exists a shortcut (or script) for xCode to Run project on all my devices plugged at the same time? I use iPhone 4S, iPhone 3G and iPod regularly to test my App, ¿Exists this script for doing it more quickly? Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Better question to ask is, how to create a script to run on all devices, that I think is possible.

Comment: An upvote would be a good indicator that you are not being sarcastic.